# TinyGPS (Plus) Library

Tags: arduino-ide, library, gps, tinygps

Is there a particular function in the library TinyGPS or TinyGPS Plus which outputs the raw NMEA sentences? I couldn't find anything about it on the website guide of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be, but what you could do is print each character as it arrives. From their example code:

```C++
  while (nss.available())
  {
    if (gps.encode(nss.read()))    // <--- pass to TinyGPS
      return true;
  }
```

So, change that to be:

```C++
  while (nss.available())
  {
    char c = nss.read();  // <--- get the incoming character
    Serial.print (c);     // <--- print it
    if (gps.encode(c))    // <--- now pass it to TinyGPS
      return true;
  }
```